# Poisson approximation of $X$ by $Poisson(E[X])$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, asymptotics, approximation, expectation

I've tried to find something, but couldn't find anything about the following question.

Is it possible to approximate any random variable $X$ with $E[X]=o(1)$ by a Poisson random variable $Poisson(E[X])$.

Especially, I would like to Show that

$$Pr[X \geq x] \sim Pr[Poisson(E[X])\geq x]$$

for some $x=O(1)$.

Do you know results on the (relative and absolute) error of this Approximation?

EDIT:
Would it help, if we knew that $X$ is a sum of Binomial random variables?
Thus $X_i \sim Bin(n_i, p_i)$ and $X=\sum_{i} X_i$ and $E[X]=\sum_i n_i p_i=o(1)$.
Can we then approximate $X$ by $Poisson(\sum_i n_i p_i)$?

Answer (score 0):

Note that the poisson distribution with parameter $\lambda$ is the limit case ($n\to \infty$) of the sum of $n$ indepent Bernouilli trials with parameter $\frac \lambda n$. Thus, if the binomials have a large coefficient, we may approximate them with a certain poisson distribution, and then we can just replace the sum of the poisson distributions by a single poisson distribution.

Comment: thanks for your answer. this is, what I wanted to do. 
But I couldn't find a site stating the relative error of this Approximation, thus telling me whether indeed
$Pr[X\geq x ] \sim Pr[Poisson(E[X]) \geq x]$. I would really appreciate if you could help me a Little bit with this or link a paper ( I didn't find any).

Comment: My first Problem is, that I can't find a good paper for the realtive error of the poisson Approximation. And the second is: 
even if I found one, I am not sure how to Combine These Errors for the sum.

Comment: Sorry, i don't think I can help you with the errors.